# Overloading with single arg and varargs

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

Let's say I have the following 2 functions:

```
public foo(String str){
    System.out.println(str);
}

public foo(String... str){
    System.out.println("varargs");
    for(String s: str){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Will it compile?
If it will which foo will be called with foo("hi")?

Comment: There's an easy way to find out.

Comment: if only there was some way of checking

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pressing the 'run' button should've been your first course of action.

Comment: …or looking at well-known examples like [`EnumSet.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/EnumSet.html) whose overloads exist because it works…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it compile?

No. Because both of your methods lack a return type.

If you set it to `void`:

```
public void foo(String str){
    System.out.println(str);
}

public void foo(String... str){
    System.out.println("varargs");
    for(String s: str){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

then it will compile.

> If it will which foo will be called with `foo("hi")`?

The `foo(String str)` method will be called and you could easily check it.